# Node.js Express for REST? Are there controllers in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, javascriptmvc

I'm currently developing a community (like a lightweight "social network") for a limited (local) target.
This is the first project where SEO doesn't matter and where I can happily exclude no-js users. That's why I'm thinking to start the project over and write my first site that is **completely build with Javascript** and my **first Node application** for educational reasons.

Details so far:

**Browser: jQuery**, maybe **JavaScriptMVC** (there are some things I don't like about JavaScriptMVC (like the routes), maybe I write my own little MVC or **do you know a better suited framework?**)

**Server: Node.JS**, **Express** framework, (maybe socket.io or nowjs for further features)

I got a few questions so far. I know it's better to ask a single question but there are more or less connected:

- **Express** looks really nice but I'm **missing MVC**. I couldn't find any project that implements mvc and is build on Express. Is there a reason for that? Routing is nice in Express but I need a way to spread code across multiple files (controllers would be the best way I guess, the application won't be small and I need it maintainable)
- The application will be more or less **completely based on AJAX** (json) requests. **Is Express the right framework for such applications**, anyway? I think the best way to write this project is to expose a **json REST api** which can then be queried by the web application over AJAX and by a mobile device app (which I'm also going to write). In my opinion Express' route system is quite suited for REST. But feel free to recommend other frameworks.

Comment: For RESTful apps with express, I just started to play with https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource . Looks promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your primary question, yes there are controllers in Express. They are more akin to Sinatra (express is modeled after Sinatra rather than Rails). By that I mean they are light-weight method mappings to routes you define.

> Browser: jQuery, maybe JavaScriptMVC (there are some things I don't
> like about JavaScriptMVC (like the routes), maybe I write my own
> little MVC or do you know a better suited framework?

I'd go with [spine.js](http://spinejs.com/) or [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) personally.

> Express looks really nice but I'm missing MVC. I couldn't find any
> project that implements mvc and is build on Express. Is there a reason
> for that? Routing is nice in Express but I need a way to spread code
> across multiple files (controllers would be the best way I guess, the
> application won't be small and I need it maintainable)

You can spread files out all you want. I answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732293/node-js-express-js-breaking-up-the-app-js-file/7732669#7732669).

> The application will be more or less completely based on AJAX (json)
> requests. Is Express the right framework for such applications,
> anyway? I think the best way to write this project is to expose a json
> REST api which can then be queried by the web application over AJAX
> and by a mobile device app (which I'm also going to write). In my
> opinion Express' route system is quite suited for REST. But feel free
> to recommend other frameworks.

I haven't built a 1 page app yet in node but from what I can tell, almost everyone seems to be using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) with [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/). That's not to say you can't, just that you'll find more examples that way.

Comment: I don't know if socket.io is too heavy for just showing sites. However it'd be nice to broadcast status messages in realtime and I think I'm going to implement a chat later, so I'd need it anyway. But then I still need REST or similar for the mobile application. Hmm, so many ways :D.

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen [Swagger](https://web.archive.org/web/20171005065017/http://swagger.wordnik.com:80/)? An API server available in Node.js with an [automated UI Generator](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui).

[image: Swagger]
<sub>(source: [wordnik.com](http://swagger.wordnik.com/images/swagger_screenshot.png?1312911996))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Sails](http://github.com/balderdashy/sails).  Its structure is based on Rails.