# Node.js: Configuration and routes in a different file

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, express

I am starting a new Node.js app and this time, I'm trying to organize the code correctly instead of having everything in the same file.

I only have a simple setup now at `server.coffee`:

```
express = require 'express'
app = module.exports = express.createServer()

## CONFIGURATION ##

app.configure () ->
 app.set 'views', __dirname + '/views'
 app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
 app.use express.bodyParser()
 app.use express.logger('dev')
 app.use express.profiler()
 app.use express.methodOverride()
 app.use app.router
 app.use express.static(__dirname + '/public')

app.configure 'development', () ->
 app.use express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true})

app.configure 'production', () ->
 app.use express.errorHandler()

app.get '/', (req,res) ->
  res.render 'index'
    title: 'Express'

## SERVER ##
port = process.env.PORT || 3000 

app.listen port, () ->
  console.log "Listening on port" + port
```

I have some questions regarding that simple code and I know that all the answers depend on the developer but I really want to do it right:

- Should the `server.js` file have more than the `app.listen`? What should be there exactly?
- Shouldn't all the configurations be in a different file than the routes? How can I remove the `app.get` to other file and make them work when I run the `server.coffee`?
- What exactly should contain the `index.coffee` that I see in a lot of apps like Hubot?

I hope someone can give me an answer other than "it depends".

Answer (score 35):

You can leverage `require`, and simply pass the `app` var in as a parameter to a method. It's not the prettiest syntax, nor is it in CoffeeScript, but you should get the idea.

#### routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    // set up the routes themselves
    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
        // do stuff
    });
};
```

#### app.js

```
require("./routes")(app);
```

If you want to take it a step further, I separate my routes into smaller groups, and in it's own subfolder. (like: `routes/auth.js` for login/logout, `routes/main.js` for home/about/contact and so on)

#### routes/index.js

```
// export a function that accepts `app` as a param
module.exports = function (app) {
    require("./main")(app);
    // add new lines for each other module, or use an array with a forEach
};
```

(rename `routes.js` from before as `routes/main.js`, the source itself remains the same)

Comment: thanks @Dominic this is what I was looking for, an advice on how to make an application architecture. expressjs guys should have something like this on their page.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the example regarding express.Router() http://expressjs.com/migrating-4.html#express-router it is very similar to this, but it helped me get my head around this even more.

Comment: The link above is broken.

Comment: @Nick Pineda: the link is http://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html.  There's no "#express-router" anchor anymore - you just have to scroll down to "express.Router" ... or "birds.js".

Answer (score 7):

Express 4 [simplifies](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html) this with the `express.Router` class.

> The other feature to help organize routes is a new class, `express.Router`, that you can use to create modular mountable route handlers. A `Router` instance is a complete middleware and routing system; for this reason it is often referred to as a “mini-app”.
>
> The following example creates a router as a module, loads a middleware in it, defines some routes, and mounts it on a path on the main app.
>
> Create a router file named `birds.js` in the app directory, with the following content:
>
> ```
> var express = require('express');
> var router = express.Router();
>
> // middleware specific to this router
> router.use(function timeLog(req, res, next) {
>   console.log('Time: ', Date.now());
>   next();
> });
>
> // define the home page route
> router.get('/', function(req, res) {
>   res.send('Birds home page');
> });
>
> // define the about route
> router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
>   res.send('About birds');
> });
>
> module.exports = router;
> ```
>
> Then, load the router module in the app:
>
> ```
> var birds = require('./birds');
> app.use('/birds', birds);
> ```
>
> The app will now be able to handle requests to `/birds` and `/birds/about`, along with calling the `timeLog` middleware specific to the route.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 similar question that can help you a lot with this:

[How to structure a express.js application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732293/node-js-express-js-breaking-up-the-app-js-file)

[Nodejs/Expressjs app structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428212/nodejs-expressjs-app-structure)