# Node.js: Has anyone integrated Mongoose-Auth/EveryAuth with Express in a MVC way?

Tags: model-view-controller, node.js, express, mongoose, everyauth

Does anyone have an example repo that integrates Mongoose-Auth with Everyauth in a MVC organized Express application?

I realize that's probably a stretch, but any help or pointers on how to integrate Mongoose-Auth/Everyauth with a MVC structure are appreciated. I'm having trouble trying to put all of the pieces for Mongoose-Auth into the MVC structure of my project. I'd share, but it's a bit of a mess right now and not helpful.

I started my project using this MVC with Express and Mongoose example:

https://github.com/qed42/nodejs-express-mongoose-demo

Comment: Everyauth is just one big massive controller. So just put it in your controller folder o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've checked the documentation for [mongoose-auth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth) it seems the only connection it has is with the model, so I suggest you make a user model and put the mongoose-auth stuff in there.

By the way, you structure looks good in my opinion.

Resources:

[How to structure a express.js application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732293/node-js-express-js-breaking-up-the-app-js-file)

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/mvc