# How to apply an mvc approach to the app.js file in a nodejs - express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been following some nodejs - mongodb - express tutorials. I understand some of the basics such as the

- the general principal of using `app.js` as a main (for want of a better term) controller for the site.
- Storing all third party modules in their own `node_modules` directory.
- Placing html/template engine files in `views`
- Using the `public` directory as you might the `skin` folder in a php project

I'm trying to combine some of the things that I've come across in a lot of the tutorials and the one thing that is troubling me is how condensed the `app.js` folder is becoming. This [`breaking-up-the-app`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732293/node-js-express-js-breaking-up-the-app-js-file) question is very similar to mine but I'm looking for a less subjective reply I think. The accepted answer suggests a method that he uses

```
~/app
|~controllers
| |-monkey.js
| |-zoo.js
|~models
| |-monkey.js
| |-zoo.js
|~views
| |~zoos
|   |-new.jade
|   |-_form.jade
|~test
|  |~controllers
|    |-zoo.js
|  |~models
|    |-zoo.js
|-index.js
```

I like how this looks and would like to implement something similar on my project.

**For Example**

I'm using the `active-menu` module and it seems to take up a lot of space in my app.js

```
//menu
var activeMenu = require('active-menu');
// Create a New Instance
var adminMenu = new activeMenu('adminMenu');
// Set HTML Attributes for the Top <ul> element
adminMenu.setAttributes({class : 'menu', id : 'admin-menu'});
// Home Node
var homeNode = adminMenu.addMenuNode('Home', '/');
homeNode.setAttributes({class : 'home home-icon', id : 'home-link'});

var postsNode = adminMenu.addMenuNode('About', '/about');
postsNode.setAttributes({class : 'about about-icon'});

var newPostNode = postsNode.addMenuNode('Contact', '/contact');
newPostNode.setAttributes({class : 'contact-post contact-icon'});

var app = express();

// Use Menu
app.use(adminMenu.menu);
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/active-menu) to achieve that. It works so the tutorial served it's purpose but it would be better if inside my `controller` directory I could get the links dynamically somehow and just reference `app.use(adminMenu.menu);` so that it could be called in the layout.jade so how can I write this?

The same seems be the case for the app.get/put/post/delete etc. Based on [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61078/write-simple-node-jsmongodb-web-service-ios-app) I came to have this also in my app.js file.

```
app.get('/:collection', function(req, res) { 
var params = req.params; 
collectionDriver.findAll(req.params.collection, function(error, objs) { 
      if (error) { res.send(400, error); } 
      else { 
          if (req.accepts('html')) {
              res.render('data',{objects: objs, collection: req.params.collection}); 
          } else {
              res.set('Content-Type','application/json'); //G
              res.send(200, objs); //H
          }
       }
    });
});

app.get('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) { //I
    var params = req.params;
    var entity = params.entity;
    var collection = params.collection;
    if (entity) {
        collectionDriver.get(collection, entity, function(error, objs) { 
            if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
            else { res.send(200, objs); } //K
        });
    } else {
        res.send(400, {error: 'bad url', url: req.url});
    }
});

app.post('/:collection', function(req, res) {
    var object = req.body;
    var collection = req.params.collection;
    collectionDriver.save(collection, object, function(err,docs) {
        if (err) { res.send(400, err); } 
        else { res.send(201, docs); } //B
    });
 });

app.put('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) { //A
    var params = req.params;
    var entity = params.entity;
    var collection = params.collection;
    if (entity) {
        collectionDriver.update(collection, req.body, entity, function(error, objs) { //B
            if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
            else { res.send(200, objs); } //C
         });
    } else {
        var error = { "message" : "Cannot PUT a whole collection" };
        res.send(400, error);
    }
});

app.delete('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) { //A
    var params = req.params;
    var entity = params.entity;
    var collection = params.collection;
    if (entity) {
        collectionDriver.delete(collection, entity, function(error, objs) { 
           if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
           else { res.send(200, objs); } 
        });
   } else {
       var error = { "message" : "Cannot DELETE a whole collection" };
       res.send(400, error);
   }
});
```

Again how can I write this so that these calls are in a model/controller and only seen by app.js when needed?

One objective that I am hoping to achieve through this question is an understanding of how to do this **WITHOUT** an additional framework.

Some reading that I did along my way before writing this question 
- [Node Beginner](http://www.nodebeginner.org/)
- [Nodejs with express, jade and stylus](http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/a-simple-website-in-nodejs-with-express-jade-and-stylus)
- [Mongodb](http://www.marcusoft.net/2014/05/mongodb-and-10309-unable-to-createopen.html)

Comment: Sails.js? (http://sailsjs.org)

Comment: Sooner or later after following the current trend in web development you are going to switch to frontend either Angularjs, Bakbone or Ember.js to manage your front end routing, view logic. I suggest rather than sticking to views on node.js you can actually leverage the power of Angularjs on your app. So basically then express will act as REST Api engine and angular will do the job for you to fetch data from express endpoints and display.  In that way you will be having clean and scalable architecture. Let me know if you need any help on this.

Comment: if you want to use the MVC pattern without using ``express``, you may look at https://github.com/piyasde/minimalweb , there you have a pattern which comes near to your approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the question was really aimed at finding a solution other than using an additional framework I've come to the conclusion that this is not feasible.

I've decided to just go with angular.js and I couldn't recommend more [this](http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/09/28/angularjs-tutorial-for-beginners-with-nodejs-expressjs-and-mongodb/) 3 part tutorial more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current approach: https://github.com/tkiddle/expressPlate/tree/tkiddle

It's a work in progress, but does work quite well.